# How to display the code of a .C routine used by R function?

Tags: r

I was studying some functions of the package `rimage`. If you want to see, for example, the code for the `sobel.h` function, you obtain:

```
> library(rimage)
> sobel.h
function (img) 
{
    w <- dim(img)[2]
    h <- dim(img)[1]
    imagematrix(abs(matrix(.C("sobel_h", as.double(img), as.integer(w), 
        as.integer(h), eimg = double(w * h), PACKAGE = "rimage")$eimg, 
        nrow = h, ncol = w)), noclipping = TRUE)
}
```

So the `sobel.h` function uses the C routine called `sobel_h`, (which is (I think) stored in the file `rimage.dll`).

Is there any way to see the C code of the `sobel_h` function?

(I speak about the package `rimage` for a practical example; but the answer would of course generalised to all packages that uses .C routines).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check this:
[Uwe Ligges. R Help Desk: Accessing the sources. R News, 6(4):43-45, October 2006.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf)

> In order to access the sources of
>   compiled code (i.e., C, C++, or
>   Fortran), it is not sufficient to have
>   the binary version of R or a
>   contributed package installed. Rather,
>   it is necessary to download the
>   sources for R or for the package.

Answer (score 5):

The Linux source for rimage is here:
http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rimage_0.5-8.1.tar.gz
Windows source is here:
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/rimage_0.5-8.1.zip

sobel.c is in the rimage/src/ directory in the unpacked files.

Comment: There is no source in *.zip file, it contains only compiled package.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to find the source code to rimage.dll (try googling on sobel_h and rimage.dll, i found something promising)